# Qt Image help (IP camera)

Tags: qt4

I'm having a problem with the images. I want to grab it from an IP camera to use it for processing. The problem is that the images I grabbed become thumbnails. Please help. This is my code:

```
QUrl page;
ui->setupUi(this);
m_view = new QWebView(this);
m_lbl = new QLabel(this);
m_lbl->setGeometry(100, 100, 840, 636);

connect(m_view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(onLoadFinished(bool)));
page.setScheme("http");
page.setUserName("joharvie");
page.setPassword("tan");
page.setHost("10.4.2.3");
page.setPath("/snapshot.cgi");
m_view->load(page);
m_view->show();
QWebElement element = m_view->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement();
element = element.findFirst("img");
QPixmap pix(QSize(640, 480));//element.geometry().size());
QPainter painter(&pix);
element.render(&painter);
pix.save("target.jpg");
m_lbl->setPixmap(pix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the image in the page isn't a thumbnail that you click on for the full image?  - (check the page source)

Comment: I got it from the IP camera.... I tried other links still the same result. When I access it with a browser the size is 640 by 480 but if I use my program the size goes 10 by 10 i think and the remaining of the 640 by 480 is a black fill

Comment: Every IP camera i have used embeds the actual video stream in a control activeX or whatever, can you right click and save the image? What do you get if you use wget to dump the page?

Comment: actually i want it to automatically save it to the pc because we are going to use it for processing.... like save overriding the original file......

Comment: I meant as a test - in the browser van you save the image, that will check if the image is OK or if it's your code.

Comment: If I save it form the browser its fine..... but when I use my code the picture becomes a thumbnail..... even tried grabbing from other sites that only features a  singe picture